# How do I get the custom status of a user? discord.js version 13

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I'm making a bot, and I want to make a `status` command that basically displays a user's custom status. I've tried doing `interaction.member.activities.find(a => a.type === 'CUSTOM_STATUS').state` but it says it can't read `find`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because there is no `member.activities` property. It's [`member.presence.activities`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Presence?scrollTo=activities) and [its `type`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Activity?scrollTo=type) can't be `CUSTOM_STATUS`. It's one of `PLAYING`, `STREAMING`, `LISTENING`, `WATCHING`, `CUSTOM`, `COMPETING`, so you will need to find `CUSTOM`:

```js
let activity = interaction.member.presence?.activities.find(
  (a) => a.type === 'CUSTOM'
)

console.log(activity?.state)
```

PS: Make sure that the `GUILD_PRESENCES` intent is enabled (i.e. add `Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_PRESENCES` to your `client`'s `intents` array). Without that `member.presence` will be `null`.